# how to write file to another folder in python

Tags: python, security, cryptography

I am encrypting a file and it encrypts to a folder named mark but I want the file to encrypt and be placed in a sub folder named Kevin. Code is below:

```py
with open("encrypted_" + filename + '.txt', "wb") as ef:
    ef.write(encrypted_file)
```

That encrypts the file but places it in the same folder. How can i edit this so it moves to the Kevin folder after encryption. I am using Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import shutil

with open("encrypted_" + filename + '.txt', "wb") as ef:
    ef.write(encrypted_file)

shutil.move(f"encrypted_{filename}.txt", "Kevin") #f"encrypted_{filename}.txt" is the file and "Kevin" is the Destination Folder
```

Comment: You need to recreate the filename, `shutil.move("encrypted_" + filename + '"txt", "Kevin")`.

Answer (score 0):

If using linux, try to move it after encryption:

```
import shutil
shutil.move("origin_path", "destination_path")
```